# Access the JavaScriptCore engine of a UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, javascriptcore

I just discovered a new framework available in iOS7: JavaScriptCore.

It looks awesome, but how can I access the runtime/context of a `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no official mechanism for this.  But there are two approaches I know about to get the `JSContext`.  I probably wouldn't use either in a shipping app.

1. Use KVC to access internal `UIWebView` properties.  Explained in detail in this blog post:  http://blog.impathic.com/post/64171814244/true-javascript-uiwebview-integration-in-ios7

```c
JSContext *ctx = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];
```

2. Add a *magic method* to `NSObject` via a category.  Explained in more detail, here: https://github.com/TomSwift/UIWebView-TS_JavaScriptContext

```c
@implementation NSObject (magic)
- (void) webView: (id) unused didCreateJavaScriptContext: (JSContext*) ctx forFrame: (id) frame
{
    // ...
}
@end
```

Comment: Excellent. Error-prone but still nice. I don't see why Apple didn't expose this.

Comment: Looks interesting! Hopefully it will soon appear in the public API. Until then I'll try your solution :)

Comment: Your code on GitHub looks interesting, but doesn't have a license—any chance you could clarify the licensing?

Answer (score 2):

You might like to look at the WWDC 2013 Session Videos on the developer web-site (https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) and in particular 'Integrating JavaScript into Native Apps' which to quote the description "Introducing a new Objective-C API to `JavaScriptCore`. iOS developers can now integrate scripting into their apps without having to bundle custom language interpreters. This API builds on top of the existing C API to `JavaScriptCore` available on Mac, and makes programming with JavaScript much easier and less error-prone."
There is a section on using it with `WebView` e.g. using: `-webView:didCreateJavaScriptContext:forFrame:`

Comment: This looks to be only available for Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScriptCore exists so that developers have a JavaScript runtime to use from Objective-C.  The only way I'm aware of to access the UIWebView runtime is through the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method, which obviously isn't very flexible.